# Manuscript status changed to under review again after with associated editor, what could be the reason?

Tags: peer-review

Recently I submitted major revision to the IEEE journal. For 16 days, my manuscript status was showing to be under review and after that status changed to with associated editor for a day. Now status of the manuscript is changed to under review again. What is the meaning of this changes?

Comment: The basic advise for situations like these is: Submit your article and than forget it existed. Once you have submitted your article there is *nothing* you can do. Every second you spent looking at statusses, worrying, or asking questions on forums like these, is a second not spent doing something productive like writing your next paper, cooking a meal for a loved one, or just relax.

Comment: There are a lot of actors and a lot of variables. Papers can bounce around a bit before any decisions.